# jQuery Get Value of Input Field in the next Div Nest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get value of the input field nested in the next div with class 'fullaccountcode' but it keeps on returning empty when I alert the result.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 fullaccountcode">
                        <input type=text name=mcode[] id=mcode placeholder="34" class="form-control">
          </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 show-slash">
                        <span>/</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 fullaccountcode">
                        <input type=text name=ccode[] id=ccode placeholder="01" class="form-control" value="yello">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1 show-slash">
                        <span>/</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 fullaccountcode">
                        <input type=text name=sacode[] id=sacode placeholder="0016" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).on("keyup","#mcode",function() {
  alert($(this).closest('div').nextAll('.fullaccountcode').eq(0).val());
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sm2wow6w)

Comment: try replacing `.nextAll()` with `.find()` and see if it gets it :)

Comment: Please show your html code the it will be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code:

1) you are targeting div and not the input element in it. Use `.find('input')` after getting the target div element.

2 ) Also eq selector targets the element based on zero index. You should use `:eq(0)` or `.first()` to target first element in matched set:

```
$(document).on("keyup","#mcode",function() {
  alert($(this).closest('div').nextAll(".fullaccountcode").eq(0).find('input').val());
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wyaeamq6/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this).parent().next().next().find("input").val()`

```js
$(document).on("keyup","#mcode",function() {
   console.log($(this).parent().next().next().find("input").val());
    alert($(this).parent().next().next().find("input").val());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 fullaccountcode">
       <input type=text name=mcode[] id=mcode placeholder="34" class="form-control">
              </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 show-slash">
       <span>/</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 fullaccountcode">
       <input type=text name=ccode[] id=ccode placeholder="01" class="form-control" value="yello">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 show-slash">
       <span>/</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 fullaccountcode">
       <input type=text name=sacode[] id=sacode placeholder="0016" class="form-control">
      </div>
     </div>
```